# Creating Dictionary and Integer Key for List of Strings in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, token

I have a list of unicode string lists.

Each string list represents a different document with the strings representing the authors' names. Some documents have only one author while other documents can have multiple co-authors.

For example, a sample of authorship of three documents looks like this:

```
authors = [[u'Smith, J.', u'Williams, K.', u'Daniels, W.'], [u'Smith, J.'], [u'Williams, K.', u'Daniels, W.']]
```

I want to convert my list into a dictionary and list.

First, a dictionary that provides an integer key for each name:

```
author_name = {0: u'Smith, J.', 1: u'Williams, K.', 2: u'Daniels, W.'}
```

Second, a list that identifies the authors for each document by the integer key:

```
doc_author = [[0, 1, 2], [0], [1, 2]]
```

What is the most efficient way to create these?

FYI: I need my author data in this format to run a pre-built author-topic LDA algorithm written in Python.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Do you already have `author_name` dictionary, or you're also going to create it?

Comment: No. I need to create it. Any suggestions?

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​I'm not sure that I understand your question correctly: Do you mean convert the longest list in `authors` to a dictionary? If so, try `author_name = dict(enumerate(max(authors, key=len)))`.

Comment: Not necessarily. If you assume there's an additional document with a new author, then that method breaks down. For example, assume `authors = [[u'Smith, J.', u'Williams, K.', u'Daniels, W.'], [u'Smith, J.'], [u'Williams, K.', u'Daniels, W.'], [u'Johnson, A']]` then `author_name = dict(enumerate(max(authors, key=len))` doesn't capture the new author, u'Johnson, A'

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Huh, run `import itertools; author_name = []; for name in itertools.chain(*authors): if name not in author_name: author_name.append(name)`, then `author_name = dict(enumerate(max(author_name, key=len))`.

Comment: Well done Kevin! It worked on my larger dataset. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to invert your `author_name` dictionary; after that the conversion of your list is trivial, using a nested list comprehension:

```
author_to_id = {name: id for id, name in author_name.items()}

doc_author = [[author_to_id[name] for name in doc] for doc in authors]
```

Demo:

```
>>> authors = [[u'Smith, J.', u'Williams, K.', u'Daniels, W.'], [u'Smith, J.'], [u'Williams, K.', u'Daniels, W.']]
>>> author_name = {0: u'Smith, J.', 1: u'Williams, K.', 2: u'Daniels, W.'}
>>> author_to_id = {name: id for id, name in author_name.items()}
>>> [[author_to_id[name] for name in doc] for doc in authors]
[[0, 1, 2], [0], [1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst=['person', 'bicycle', 'car', 'motorbike', 'bus', 'truck' ]
dct = {}

for key, val in enumerate(lst):
    dct[key] = val

print(dct)


***output***
{0: 'person', 1: 'bicycle', 2: 'car', 3: 'motorbike', 4: 'bus', 5: 'truck'}
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32337735)

Answer (score 0):

```
### list of lists
authors = [[u'Smith, J.', u'Williams, K.', u'Daniels, W.'], [u'Smith, J.'], [u'Williams, K.', u'Daniels, W.']]


###flat lists
flat_list = [x for xs in authors for x in xs]
# print(flat_list)

### remove duplicates
res = [*set(flat_list)]
# print(res)

### create dict
dct = {}
for key, val in enumerate(res):
    dct[key] = val

print(dct)


**output**

{0: 'Daniels, W.', 1: 'Williams, K.', 2: 'Smith, J.'}
```